# Corrupted the System partition on RAID configuration after a BIOS update, how do I recover data?

Tags: windows-7, bios, raid, data-recovery

**Problem:**

After an ASUS BIOS update to improve stability for 45 nm quad-core processors.

On the next reboot, got the Windows Loading screen, and then a blue screen. Rebooted again, another blue screen.

I have 2 partitions `C:` and `D:` I need a way to get the data off my `D:` partition so I can wipe the entire system out and start over, but I can't see the data on `D:`.

I know it's there; I can see it listed in the ASUS EzFlash 2 utility I used to do the BIOS update.

**What I've tried:**

I tried reverting to the previous BIOS, it still blue screens.

So I popped in my shiny new Windows 7 DVD and did a "Repair my computer."

> It found an issue with my boot configuration so I told it to fix it.

Rebooted, blue screen.

Then I remembered  that I had previously had my system configured with two 640GB hard drives sharing a mirrored `C:` (Master) and `D:` (Data) partitions, and realized that the BIOS update reverted the HD configuration to IDE, so I flipped it back to RAID.  Reboot, No OS installed.

Popped the Win7 DVD back it, did a "Repair my Computer", it found more problems with the boot configuration so I told it to fix it, it told me that it couldn't.

> I tried reformatting the `C:` but now it's just a "Primary" partition and not a System one.

Now I'm sitting with no bootable drives, a ton of data on my `D:` partition that I can't get to, and I'm stumped.

> Next I tried a Linux Live CD (Kubuntu 9.04).

I thought this would be a life saver, but I can't mount the existing `C:` or `D:` Windows partitions.

> Fdisk is telling me that they are FAT16 partitions, not NTFS. I'm guessing it's because of the RAID configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I figured it out.

I installed the 'dmraid' package and activated the RAID partitions. After some trial and error, I was able to mount my data partition and copy the files off onto the external.

What a fiasco... and a learning experience.